# Looking foward to the Message

Tags: cipher, cryptic-clues

Some words of wisdom from a good friend of mine. He sent it to me in a form of a puzzle for me to work out:

*1) Integral - killer's initials and victims end (3)*

*2) Stiff, dull-spoken. (5)*

*3) Sheep blended with ruins of Israeli city for bakers (6)*

*Only a little left! Here it is...*

> AGFKGVHMHGBWBJVHJ

HINTS:

1.

> There is also a clue beneath the cryptic clues.

2. 

> For those struggling with the 3rd cryptic clue, it refers to a well-known phrase...

3. 

> The first clue refers to something metallic the second something usually brown.

4. 

> Can you give me the baker's no. I want him to be my chef.

Comment: Just wondering why is this puzzle so unpopular?

Comment: What do you mean by "unpopular"? It's on a score of zero, which isn't terribly unusual, especially for a puzzle that was only posted 9 hours ago. No one's answered it, but that could be "hard" as easily as "unpopular".

Comment: I was wondering why cryptic clue puzzle don't do as well as the TM puzzles, is there something wrong with them?

Comment: And my riddle tio? How can I get more upvotes on them?

Comment: Some puzzles attract people's attention more than others, mostly at random. I do have a conjecture, though, which is that a puzzle _where it's hard to tell before seeing the solution whether it's any good_ is less likely to get early upvotes and solution attempts. (That doesn't apply so much if it's set by someone with a long good track record.)

Comment: E.g., lots of people trying to write cryptic crossword clues do it badly, and a badly-set cryptic crossword clue is liable to be unsolvable. I don't know of any particular reason to think that your clues are bad, of course! But for all I know they _might_ be. If a substantial fraction of PSE folks looking at this puzzle think "hmm, a bunch of cryptic clues that might turn out to be no good, doesn't seem like much fun" then it's likely to get less attention than some other puzzles might.

Comment: That doesn't mean no one will ever try to solve it or that it'll be stuck for ever at 0. I don't know about everyone else, but I expect I'll take a look at it from time to time, and maybe at some point I'll solve one of the cryptic clues, which will give me some idea of whether the others are likely to be good. If it looks like they are I'll try harder :-).

Comment: I see so set an easy one as a bait.

Comment: Riddles have the same issue: many attempts at making riddles are really bad, and many more are _fairly_ bad, and bad riddles are no fun to solve because they tend to be mostly about trying to guess what not-necessarily-very-coherent ideas were in the creator's head.

Comment: Your riddle has a few things in it that look like warning signs: e.g., things like "of sorts", "you could say", "?!" all _could_ be indications that the cluing in it doesn't really work very well and you're aware of the fact. (Which, to be clear, would be much better than if it didn't work very well and you _weren't_ aware of it.) Maybe actually it's all fine. But again you should expect a bit of skepticism.

Comment: I'm not sure about "set an easy one as bait". Setting puzzles that are very easy also doesn't make a good impression (my usual thought is "if they think that's a challenging question then maybe they aren't all that bright and their other questions are likely not to be very interesting"...).

Comment: I mean a part of the puzzle.

Comment: So would you say this is too hard?

Comment: I've no idea yet whether it's too easy, too hard or just right. Or whether it's well constructed or not. Or anything. Once it's solved (whether by me or by someone else) it will be easier to tell.

Comment: I agree with everything Gareth has said. One thing that may be helpful (and I wouldn't normally advise) is to consider changing your username. Personally, it doesn't bother me and, on this puzzle, I would prefer to make a decision on voting once somebody has got the answer. However, it's likely that some people will be put off by giving reputation to someone who has named themselves "Smartest1here".

Comment: Also, votes can come in quickly after a puzzle is solved and realized as bad, good, or a gem.  The waiting game is also a learning game.

Comment: One further bit of feedback (meant well) - try to avoid making *accruing reputation* your main aim on PSE. Leave behind the mindset of thinking of puzzles (or their components) as 'bait', and don't *expect* reputation - nobody owes it to anyone else, just for writing a question or an answer. Focus on making interesting puzzles, challenging yourself to come up with imaginative new things, and writing thorough, fully thought-through answers. Rep is the community's way of showing appreciation for good effort - try hard, act on feedback, and most importantly: do it just to *enjoy* it! :)

Comment: With this, I think I've solved 1) and 2) and I understand the hint but 3) seems essential to getting it and I haven't figured that out.

Comment: Oops there was a little error look at the edit

Comment: Puzzles are upvoted for two (main) reasons. Either someone solved it and thought it was a good one or they can see that it is clever without necessarily having solved it yet. Word puzzles are more easily created and then jumbled - the solutions may not be unique, the puzzle may not be solvable. Until there are answers people usually can't tell whether it is a good puzzle. Also from someone whose username claims they're the smartest here perhaps expectations are higher.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the message is

> NEW YEAR FRESH START

1. Integral - killer's initials and victims end (3)

> KEY = "Integral" is the definition with "killer's initials" being K with victim's end indicating the last two letters of PREY (thanks OP for clarification).

2. Stiff, dull-spoken. (5)

> This is BOARD (which sounds like BORED = "dull-spoken")

3. Sheep blended with ruins of Israeli city for bakers (6)

> This is TWELVE which is EWE mixed up with TLV (ruins of TEL AVIV?) and bakers indicates BAKER'S DOZEN.

So overall we have

> KEYBOARD TWELVE

and together with the hint "Only a little left!" we

> Shift the encrypted text back 12 spaces on the keyboard (equivalent to a rot-14 cipher based on QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM) so that AGFKGVHMHGBWBJVHJ becomes **NEWYEARFRESHSTART**.

Comment: Excellent Hexomino, you seem to have a knack for answering my questions !

Comment: Ey is the end of 'Prey'.